# Getting 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in Windows Phone 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to run a background task using ScheduledAgent in Windows Phone 8.
Everything gets compiled properly, but when I run the app on Emulator/Device, I get a crash saying

**"'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in System.Windows.ni.dll"**

The same code runs properly in Windows Phone 7.

For Windows Phone 8 I am using Visual Studio 2012

For Windows Phone 7 I am using Visual Studio 2010

Comment: And how are we supposed to find the issue without seeing the code?

Comment: You're probably trying to get a file that: does not exist/is mispelled etc.

Can you have more detail in your exception, maybe in debug mode, or try to post your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was because I missed adding the background agent dll in the main application. Once I add that all seems to be fine :-)